# My makefile isn't finding my include paths

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, include-path

Simply put: It's not finding the include paths:

```
CC = g++
OBJS = *.o #*/*.o

DEBUG = -g
PNAME = game
INCLUDES = -Iheaders

CFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system $(DEBUG)

all: build

build: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $(PNAME)

clean:
    \rm *.o *~ $(PNAME)

.cpp:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $(.SOURCE)
```

Comment: A makefile doesn't do anything with include paths.  I think you mean that the *compiler* doesn't find the include paths...  What is the error message you get from the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your makefile looks pretty broken to me.  Firstly, you probably want:

```
OBJS = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(wildcard *.cpp))
```

Secondly, your final rule needs to be something more like:

```
%.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $^ -o $@
```

Comment: Complex makefiles aren't my forte.

Comment: @Mike: To clarify, `OBJS = *.o` literally pastes the string `*.o` everywhere `$(OBJS)` appears; this is very rarely what you want.  The above version sets the value of `OBJS` to a list of all .cpp files, with the suffixes replaced by .o (remember that the object files don't yet exist, so you can't search for them!).  The modified rule expresses how to build any .o file from it corresponding .cpp file.  `$^` and `$@` are special variables that resolve to the dependency (i.e. the .cpp) and the target (i.e. the .o), respectively.

Comment: I knew about the nature of macros in makefiles, just not the latter. Thanks.